# Beautiful Soup 4 parse line

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How would I parse the following line with BS4 and python3? I would like to extract "BH" and "Bahrain".

```
<li><input class="checkboxSelect2" name="countries[]" type="checkbox" value="BH"/> Bahrain</li>
```

I can get "Bahrain", but I can't get "BH"

```
for l in allCountries.findAll("li"):
  print(l.value)
  print(l.text)
```

l.text will return Bahrain but l.value is not valid and throws an error.

Comment: Please show how `allCountries` gets its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out how to access the attributes. i needed to first do

```
l.input
```

Then I needed to call the attribute

```
l.input.attrs['value']
```

My final code for extracting all Country names and Country Abreviations

```
for l in allCountries.findAll("li"):
  try:
    print("Country: {0} ABR: {1}".format(l.text, l.input.attrs['value']))
  except:
    pass
```